# PrimeFaces p:message shows error unreadable messages

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 7 with JSF 2.3 Mojarra and have the problem that sometimes error messages, which I place below an UI component are not readable, as shown below:
[image: error message not readable]

This is my xhtml code snippet, which is wrapped in a `<h:body>` and `<h:form>`:

```html
<p:inputNumber id="highestPriceAmountId" value="#{....}"/>
<p:message for="highestPriceAmountId" style="color: red">
    <p:autoUpdate/>
</p:message>
```

My bean snippet:

```java
UIComponent component = getUIComponentById("highestPriceAmountId");
String errorHeader = "blabla";
String errorMessage = "hahaha"
    
getFacesContext().addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorHeader, errorMessage));
PrimeFaces.current().focus(uiComponentId, component);
```

Why is the message shown like this?

Comment: Probably due to custom styling. Please, disable all custom styles and try again.

Comment: .. and try without `style="color: red"`.

Comment: removing style="color: red" solved the problem. Thank you!